# Converting timedelta values to a float with n-decimals

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I see multiple questions, but cannot find the exact answer.

I have a column of `timedelta` values

Example of a value

```
Timedelta('46 days 15:40:17.248459959')
```

How to convert it to the float `46.65297741`?

Please give a tip, or navigate to a write solution in a previous answer.

Comment: Surely you checked this discussion already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502927/from-timedelta-to-float-days-in-pandas

Comment: Perfect! df['total_days_td'] = df['time_delta'] / pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='D')